# Как узнать, куда пишется файл?

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

Код:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = createNewBitmap(dailyGoods);
    Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput("a111.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        Log.e(TAG, "bitmap written");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Судя по логам, исключений нет. Но файл пишется непонятно куда (если вообще пишется). Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш файл сохраняется в пути `корневая папка/data/data/<your_project_package/files/`

Comment: корневая папка файловой системы девайса?

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов да. Вы также можете сохранить файл в любом удобном для вас месте.

Comment: А тут можете помочь? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675306/Как-записать-файл-через-fileoutputstream-во-внутреннюю-память-приложения

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов ответил на тот вопрос

Answer (score 0):

@РасулА-ев конечно пишет все правильно, но позволю немного уточнить.

Пишется в каталог:

```
Context.getFilesDir();
```

Если разработчик не переопределял сей метод, то путь по умолчанию кажет на `/data/data/<project-package>/files`

Надеюсь ТС не будет спрашивать меня что такое `Context` :)