# Как записать файл через FileOutputStream во внутреннюю память приложения?

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

В интернете есть огромное количество решений, но я пока не нашёл следующего, удовлетворяющего двум условиям (это важно):

1. Запись через `FileOutputStream` (потому что нужно записать `Bitmap.compress()`, а это делается только через FOS).
2. Записать его во внутреннюю память приложения (на Developers есть решение записать во внутреннюю память телефона, это не то).

Нужен готовый код. Спасибо.

UPD. Лог для Расула А-ева:

```
06-05 00:04:58.177 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch E/ChartsGraphicsFactory: enter.bitmap
06-05 00:04:58.178 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch E/ChartsGraphicsFactory: android.graphics.Bitmap@cd37edc
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0a111.png (Permission denied)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.util.ChartsGraphicsFactory.createChartImage(ChartsGraphicsFactory.java:49)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.foodstuffs.GoodInDayRation.<init>(GoodInDayRation.java:44)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.util.FillArchiveScrypt.fillArchiveWithDefaultData(FillArchiveScrypt.java:39)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
06-05 00:04:58.179 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
06-05 00:04:58.180 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
06-05 00:04:58.180 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 00:04:58.180 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-05 00:04:58.180 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
06-05 00:04:58.180 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-05 00:04:58.180 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
06-05 00:04:58.180 21602-21602/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

UPD 2:

```
06-05 00:13:37.196 2941-2941/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch E/ChartsGraphicsFactory: enter.bitmap
06-05 00:13:37.196 2941-2941/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch E/ChartsGraphicsFactory: android.graphics.Bitmap@14a2cea9
06-05 00:13:37.196 2941-2941/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcarda111.png: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Comment: массив байт подходит под определение внутрення память приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Путь к внутреннему хранилищу
    String baseFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();        
    // Путь файла
    File file = new File(baseFolder + "/a111.png");
    Bitmap bitmap = createNewBitmap(dailyGoods);
    Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        Log.e(TAG, "bitmap written");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Для sdk>23 сначала надо предоставить разрешение.

```
  if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Если у нас нет разрешения
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1
        );
    }
```

Comment: Permission denied. Не подскажете, какой Permission тут нужен?

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов добавьте в манифесте `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: А это точно запись во внутреннюю память приложения? Не на флэшку?

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов Вроде так должно быть

Comment: Всё равно Permission denied

Comment: Добавил логи в вопрос.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов, если вы на девайсе с ОС>6 тестируете, то разрешение на запись надо в рантайме у юзера спрашивать

Comment: У вас sdk выше 23?

Comment: Да, выше. Сейчас попробую на 21. Разрешение у юзера спрашивается на этапе установки или при работе приложения?

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов Дополнил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Обновил логи. Пытается записать на SD. Это не ок.

Comment: `File file = new File(baseFolder + "/a111.png");` нужно было слэш добавить. Теперь все должно работать.

Comment: Да, спасибо, так работает. Но пишет вроде на внешний накопитель.